# Limiting uses' access in a monorepo

Tags: git, github, monorepo

If you're working on a large monorepo, and you wanna limit some users' access to specific directories (packages) in that monorepo, is there a better way to do this than using git submodules?

For example if you have that monorepo structure

```
- packages
  - package A
  - package B
  - package C
  - common
```

And you wanna allow a user to read and write to `package A` and `common` only. Is using git submodules the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Git, read access limitation means a repository is "private" for some users.
And a monorepo with submodules:

- is not really a monorepo
- would fail cloning for those users, because it would try cloning each submodules

One authorization system which can limit at least write access per folder is [gitolite](https://gitolite.com/gitolite/overview.html) (if you have control of your remote server).
Limiting read access inside one (mono)repo is tricky (or impossible).

Comment: I guess using gitolite is a good option, but I was wondering if there's a way to do this on Github. Thanks for that recommendation!

Comment: @AmrElsekilly No, on GitHub, there would not be a simple way to limit *read* access within a monorepo.